# Transversing through nested JSON object

Tags: javascript

I have this sample object:

```
{
   "tracks":[
      {
         "track1":{
            "friendly-name":"Track 1",
            "items":[
               {
                  "type":"prep",
                  "order":1
               },
               {
                  "type":"plan",
                  "order":2
               }
            ]
         },
         "track2":{
            "friendly-name":"Track 2",
            "items":[
               {
                  "type":"prep",
                  "order":1
               },
               {
                  "type":"plan",
                  "order":2
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

When I try the following script, I get a strange response:

```js
var paths_json = {"tracks":[{"track1":{"friendly-name":"Track 1","items":[{"type":"prep","order":1},{"type":"plan","order":2}]},"track2":{"friendly-name":"Track 2","items":[{"type":"prep","order":1},{"type":"plan","order":2}]}}]};

for (var i in paths_json) {
  for (var j in paths_json[i]) {
    for (var track in paths_json[i][j]) {
      for (var track_details in paths_json[i][j][track]) {
        console.log("key = " + track_details + ", value = " + paths_json[i][j][track][track_details]);

        for (var track_item in paths_json[i][j][track][track_details]) {
          console.log("key = " + track_item + ", value = " + paths_json[i][j][track][track_details][track_item]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get a strange response:

```
path.html:195 key = friendly-name, value = Track 1
path.html:198 key = 0, value = T
path.html:198 key = 1, value = r
path.html:198 key = 2, value = a
path.html:198 key = 3, value = c
path.html:198 key = 4, value = k
path.html:198 key = 5, value =  
path.html:198 key = 6, value = 1
path.html:195 key = items, value = [object Object],[object Object]
path.html:198 key = 0, value = [object Object]
path.html:198 key = 1, value = [object Object]
path.html:195 key = friendly-name, value = Track 2
path.html:198 key = 0, value = T
path.html:198 key = 1, value = r
path.html:198 key = 2, value = a
path.html:198 key = 3, value = c
path.html:198 key = 4, value = k
path.html:198 key = 5, value =  
path.html:198 key = 6, value = 2
path.html:195 key = items, value = [object Object],[object Object]
path.html:198 key = 0, value = [object Object]
path.html:198 key = 1, value = [object Object]
```

I am trying to capture `friendly-name` and the `type` and `order` under `items`. Also, is there a way to just start at `tracks` without having to begin at `i` and `j`?

The desired response is to `console.log` the `friendly-name`, and the `type` & `order` under items.

Comment: What's strange about the response?

Comment: Can you attach an expected/required response?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Also that is not JSON. That is a POJO

Comment: You're iterating through the characters of the string `Track 1`

Comment: @mplungjan POJO? piece of javascript object?

Comment: Plain old JavaScript object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not iterate in the next level unless the value there is an object.

And you shouldn't try to concatenate the value if it's an object.

Rather than using generic loops, just extract the specific keys you want. And use `forEach()` rather than `for` loops, to make it more readable.

```js
var paths_json = {"tracks":[{"track1":{"friendly-name":"Track 1","items":[{"type":"prep","order":1},{"type":"plan","order":2}]},"track2":{"friendly-name":"Track 2","items":[{"type":"prep","order":1},{"type":"plan","order":2}]}}]};

paths_json.tracks.forEach(track =>
  Object.values(track).forEach(t => {
    console.log(`friendly name: ${t['friendly-name']}`);
    t.items.forEach(item => console.log(`type: ${item.type}, order: ${item.order}`));
  })
);
```

Comment: The desired response is to console.log the `friendly-name`, and the `type` & `order` under `items`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the specific values you need, there is no need to traverse the object the way you are. For an example, say you wanted to log the friendly name, first type and order of a track:

```js
var paths_json = {"tracks":[{"track1":{"friendly-name":"Track 1","items":[{"type":"prep","order":1},{"type":"plan","order":2}]},"track2":{"friendly-name":"Track 2","items":[{"type":"prep","order":1},{"type":"plan","order":2}]}}]};

// loop thru the keys of paths_json.tracks[0]
Object.keys(paths_json.tracks[0]).forEach(key=>{
  //use key to get item
   const obj = paths_json.tracks[0][key]
   console.log(`friendlyName: ${obj["friendly-name"]}`)
   obj.items.forEach( ({type,order},i )=>{
       console.log(`  type#${i+1}: ${type}`);
       console.log(`  order#${i+1}: ${order}`);
   });
});
```

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: This does not work as it only returns `0` position of `items` (there's 2 objects in `items`)

Comment: sry i wasnt sure if you wanted all items or just the first

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the value is an object or not.

```js
const
    showKeyValue = object => {
        for (const key in object) {
            const value = object[key];
            if (value && typeof value === 'object') showKeyValue(value);
            else console.log(key, value);
        }    
    },
    data = { tracks: [{ track1: { "friendly-name": "Track 1", items: [{ type: "prep", order: 1 }, { type: "plan", order: 2 }] }, track2: { "friendly-name": "Track 2", items: [{ type: "prep", order: 1 }, { type: "plan", order: 2 }] } }] };

showKeyValue(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The desired response is to console.log the `friendly-name`, and the `type` & `order` under `items`.